# Why does the comparison ("string" > 0) return false in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string-comparison

Since "string" is a non-empty string, shouldn't it return true? How exactly does this comparison work?

Comment: Why do you expect it to be true?

Answer (score 1):

When comparing a String to a Number, JavaScript tries to convert the String to a Number to make a logical comparison.

Converting `"string"` to a Number results in `NaN`, and `NaN > 0` is `false`.

[Comparison Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators)

Answer (score 0):

This works because of typecasting and the simple fact that `NaN > 0` is false.

When applying to the `>` operator, both operands are cast to Numbers, so that comparison becomes

`Number("string") > 0` which is equivalent to `NaN > 0` which evaluates to `false`.